# Storybook 7.5.1, webpack 5 and 'StoryAnnotations<ReactRenderer, {}, {}> missing property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook

My problems is with error which occure in Footer.stories.ts in code part '(Story) => '. I use the same example as in official storybook decorator secotion but I cannot run easiest example.

And I cannot find working example with react + newest storybook and typescript.

Error message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SszCZ.png)

The case here is that I have message

```
Type '(Story: PartialStoryFn<ReactRenderer, {}>) => {}' is not assignable to type 'DecoratorFunction<ReactRenderer, {}>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<unknown, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>': type, props, keyts(2322)
```

More details:

```
import type { Decorator, Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';

const meta = {
  title: 'Example/Footer',
  component: Footer,
  // This component will have an automatically generated Autodocs entry: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/autodocs
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  parameters: {
    // More on how to position stories at: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/story-layout
    layout: 'fullscreen',
  },
} satisfies Meta<typeof Footer>;

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const LoggedIn: Story = {
  args: {
    user: {
      name: 'Jane Doe',
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => <Story />,
  ],
};

export const LoggedOut: Story = {};
```

I do not know how to deal with it. I tried to change tsconfig and lint

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "**/*.stories.{ts,tsx}"
  ],
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  }
}
```

expectation: no error
I tried to change tsconfig and lint configuration but nothing works.

Comment: There was problem with external dependency. Package from company. We can close this post.